# cmd (командная строка) удаление части текста/строки в файле

Tags: windows, cmd, командная-строка

Задача удалить в файле часть строки.
Есть файл test.txt, с содержимым:

```
backup.txt:backup.txt:Contract.xlsx,name@xxxxx.com;
backup.txt:backup.txt:Technic.xlsx,name@xxxxx.com;
backup.txt:backup.txt:Техника.xlsx,name@xxxxx.com;
```

Нужно из этого файла удалить backup.txt:, так что бы его содержание стало:

```
Contract.xlsx,name@xxxxx.com;
Technic.xlsx,name@xxxxx.com;
Техника.xlsx,name@xxxxx.com;
```

!!! Важно, что нет возможности использовать bat файлы, только одна строка cmd или powershell, среда ВИНОВС.

Пробывал:
cmd

```
сd С:/home/... && type test.txt | findstr /v backup.txt: > service_file.txt
```

Но получаю пустой файл, что и логично. Другого способа пока не нагуглил.
Просьба о помощи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В командной строке есть возможность использовать цикл `FOR` с ключом `/F` (подробно об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://ab57.ru/cmdlist/for.html)).

---

**Готовая команда:**

```
FOR /F "eol=; delims=: tokens=3" %i IN (input.txt) DO echo %i >> output.txt
```

**Объяснение:**

1. Сначала `delims=:` разделяет строку по символу двоеточия. То есть из строки

```
backup.txt:backup.txt:Contract.xlsx,name@xxxxx.com;
```

вы получите 3 группы:

```
backup.txt    backup.txt    Contract.xlsx,name@xxxxx.com;
```

далее `tokens=3` указывает, что в тело цикла нужно передавать лишь третью группу (*Contract.xlsx,name@xxxxx.com;*).

2. Теперь `echo %i >> output.txt` просто запишет это в выходной файл.
3. `eol=;` указывает, что символом конца строки является точка с запятой

---

Чтобы эта команда работала в BAT файле требуются некоторые изменения:

```
FOR /F "eol=; delims=: tokens=3" %%i IN (input.txt) DO echo %%i >> output.txt
```